# monaco-editor breakpoint functionality

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using [monaco-editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) for my project and I'm looking for breakpoints functionality.

Accordingly to [this conversation](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/558), there is no built in fun-ty and this is pity.

In [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-rendering-glyphs-in-the-margin) there some sort of this thing, but I don't see any kinda eventListener by clicking on gutter, so I can set or remove my breakpoints.

So, maybe I've missed smth. Please, tell me if someone has experience with this, because this is pretty popular editor, so there should be solution for breakpoints.

Answer (score 3):

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-listening-to-mouse-events shows `mouseDown`, `mouseMove` events over the glyph margin.

In [Visual Studio Code source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/electron-browser/debugEditorContribution.ts#L174), you can see the `editor.onMouseDown` event tests for clicks on the gutter:

```
this.toDispose.push(this.editor.onMouseDown((e: IEditorMouseEvent) => {
    const data = e.target.detail as IMarginData;
    if (e.target.type !== MouseTargetType.GUTTER_GLYPH_MARGIN || data.isAfterLines || !this.marginFreeFromNonDebugDecorations(e.target.position.lineNumber)) {
        return;
    }
    ....
```